# scripting Tor browser with marionette

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, python

Does anybody know whether it is possible to script Tor Browser with Marionette (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette)?

If I pass the `-marionette` argument to start-tor-browser, Tor browser listens locally on the port 2828 for Marionette/webdriver connections.

I have installed marionette_client in a venv as described at marionette-client.readthedocs.org.

However, if I try to follow the instructions at http://marionette-client.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#getting-started I get an error message:

```
>>> client = Marionette(host='localhost', port=2828)
>>> client.start_session()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "[...]/marionette/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/marionette/marionette.py", line 811, in start_session
    self.session = self._send_message('newSession', 'value')
  File "[...]/marionette/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/marionette/decorators.py", line 35, in _
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "[...]/marionette/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/marionette/marionette.py", line 611, in _send_message
    response = self.client.send(message)
  File "[...]/marionette/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/marionette_transport/transport.py", line 85, in send
    self.connect()
  File "[...]/marionette/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/marionette_transport/transport.py", line 79, in connect
    self.actor = response['id']
KeyError: 'id'
```

Has anybody had any success using Tor Browser with Marionette?

Answer (score 1):

> Has anybody had any success using Tor Browser with Marionette?

It was possible up to (at least) 52.3.0.

1. start the browser:

   ```
   cd tor-browser_en-US/Browser
   ./start-tor-browser -marionette
   ```
2. connect

   ```
   from marionette_driver.marionette import Marionette
   client = Marionette('localhost', port=2828)
   client.start_session()
   client.navigate("http://torproject.org")
   ```